# Nestjs prevent cron running 6 times

Tags: cron, nestjs, scheduler

I have a nestjs cron problem.

I called just one time a cron function but function running 6 times. My code is below.

```
  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_MINUTE)
   async watcher() {
const now = new Date();
     const openTravelRequests = await this.getOpenTravelRequestsByDate(now);

      if(openTravelRequests.length) {
        openTravelRequests.map(async(otr) => {
         await this.assignNewBoatToOpenTravelRequests(otr._id)
        })
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried counter but not working.

Comment: which function gets called 6 times -> watcher() ?

Comment: Did you add whatever class this is to 6 different `providers` arrays?

Comment: @mh377 yes, watcher.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel no I dont know what providers?

Comment: Check your app.module.ts. It should have your imports, providers, exports

Comment: @OğuzhanKAYA The `providers` array of the `@Module()` decorator

Comment: It is running 6 times in 6 minutes? The cron expression runs the function every minute... Please add more details of what is running and where it is being called from

Comment: @shoaib30 no it's running 6 times in 1 minute. I dont called from any function. Just running every minute